# sqlalchemy+sqlite stripping column names with dots?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy 0.7.6. I am aliasing columns with:

```
column = table.c["name"].label("foo.bar")
```

and SQLite uses only 'bar' as result field alias. Is there any workaround for that?

Example code:

```
create_table("sqlite:////tmp/test.sqlite", schema)

engine = create_engine(url)
metadata = MetaData(engine, reflect=True)
table = Table("test_table", metadata, schema=schema, autoload=True)

column = table.c["name"].label("foo.bar")
cursor = sql.expression.select([column])
row = cursor.execute().fetchone()

print "keys are: %s" % (row.keys(), )
```

Will print:

```
keys are: [u'bar']
```

instead of:

```
keys are: [u'foo.bar']
```

Works for postgres.

Here is full test code: https://gist.github.com/2506388

I've already reported that to the sqlalchemy lists, however meanwhile I would like to know if anyone else is experiencing similar problem and might have a workaround.

Comment: Simple answer is not to use dots in column names, but i'm sure you already knew that ;).

Comment: Strange> I have `SA-0.7.4` and i do get `keys are: [u'foo.bar']` when I run your code.

Comment: @van: Yeah, it is possible, as it worked in 0.7 (remember having this exact issue in March 2011 on 0.6.something)

Comment: @Stiivi: cool, then one has to compare two codebases in regards to `sqlite` and voila :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going to be patched in SQLAlchemy with an engine option. See [mailing list thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!topic/sqlalchemy/EqAuTFlMNZk) for more information.

Meanwhile, the workaround is:

```
# select is sqlalchemy.sql.expression.select() 
# each selected column was derived as column = table.c[reference].label(label_with_dot)

labels = [c.name for c in select.columns]
...
record = dict(zip(labels, row))
```

Solution after patch is :

```
conn = engine.connect().execution_options(sqlite_raw_colnames=True)
result = conn.execute(stmt)
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't use zip though. Mine looks like this:               `var_holding_query_EXECUTED = self.connection.execute(var_holding_query).fetchall()
 cols = [c.name for c in var_holding_query.columns]
df = pd.DataFrame(var_holding_query_EXECUTED, columns=cols)`