# pandas read_sql drops dot in column names

Tags: python, pandas

is that a bug or I'm doing specifically something wrong ?
I create a df, put it in a sql table, df and table have a column with a dot in it.
now when I read the df from the sql table, column names aren't the same.
I wrote this little piece of code so that people can test it.

```
import sqlalchemy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///test.sqlite')
dfin = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,2), columns=['column with a . dot', 'without'])
print(dfin)
dfin.to_sql('testtable', engine, if_exists='fail')


tables = engine.table_names()
for table in tables:
    sql = 'SELECT t.* FROM "' + table + '" t'
    dfout = pd.read_sql(sql, engine)
    print(dfout.columns)
    print dfout
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution is to pass `sqlite_raw_colnames=True` to your engine

```
In [141]: engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///', execution_options={'sqlite_raw_colnames':True})

In [142]: dfin.to_sql('testtable', engine, if_exists='fail')

In [143]: pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM testtable", engine).head()
Out[143]:
   index  column with a . dot   without
0      0             0.213645  0.321328
1      1            -0.511033  0.496510
2      2            -1.114511 -0.030571
3      3            -1.370342  0.359123
4      4             0.101111 -1.010498
```

SQLAlchemy does this stripping of dots deliberately (in some cases SQLite may store col names as "tablename.colname"), see eg [sqlalchemy+sqlite stripping column names with dots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345910/sqlalchemysqlite-stripping-column-names-with-dots) and https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!topic/sqlalchemy/EqAuTFlMNZk

---

This seems a bug, but not necessarily in the pandas `read_sql` function, as this relies on the `keys` method of the SQLAlchemy ResultProxy object to determine the column names. And this seems to truncate the column names:

```
In [15]: result = engine.execute("SELECT * FROM testtable")

In [16]: result.keys()
Out[16]: [u'index', u' dot', u'without']
```

So the question is if this is a bug in SQLAlchemy, or that pandas should make a workaround (by eg using `result.cursor.description` which gives the correct names)

For now, you can also use the sqlite fallback mode, using a DBAPI connection instead of SQLAlchemy engine (as this relies on `cursor.description`, here the correct column names are used:

```
In [20]: con = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')

In [21]: dfin.to_sql('testtable', con, if_exists='fail')

In [22]: pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM testtable", con).head()
Out[22]:
   index  column with a . dot   without
0      0             0.213645  0.321328
1      1            -0.511033  0.496510
2      2            -1.114511 -0.030571
3      3            -1.370342  0.359123
4      4             0.101111 -1.010498
```

Comment: amazing ! I couldn't find that by myself, I'm glad there are people like you here !