# pandas read_sql convers column names to lower case - is there a workaroud?

Tags: postgresql, pandas, sqlalchemy

related: [pandas read_sql drops dot in column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318722/pandas-read-sql-drops-dot-in-column-names)

I use pandas.read_sql to create a data frame from an sql query from a postgres database. 
some column aliases\names use mixed case, and I want it to propagate to the data frame.
however, pandas (or the underlining engine - SQLAlchemy as much as I know) return only lower case field names.

is there a workaround?
(besides using a lookup table and fix the values afterwards)

Comment: You can call `df.rename(columns=some_dict,inplace=True)` to rename the cols but I suspect that the loss of case is not pandas doing

Comment: this is my fallback plan, but I prefer not loosing the case information in the 1st place.

Comment: Are you using pypyodbc? This fixed the problem for me (Python 2 to Python 3 migration)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314255/how-to-make-pandas-read-sql-not-convert-all-headers-to-lower-case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postgres normalizes unquoted column names to lower case. If you have such a table:

```
create table foo ("Id" integer, "PointInTime" timestamp);
```

PostgreSQL will obey the case, but you will **have to** specify table names quoted as such:

```
select "Id", "PointInTime" from foo;
```

---

A better solution is to add column aliases, eg:

```
select name as "Name", value as "Value" from parameters;
```

And Postgres will return properly cased column names. If the problem is SQLAlchemy or pandas, then this will not suffice.